# How to properly combine an observable/subscription flow with synchronous within a function

Tags: angular, rxjs

What is the correct way to go about this sort of flow? `BarService` has a function that returns a boolean. The function either calculates the result itself or it may depend on the result of an observable call in `FooService`.

I am expecting the result of the test to be true but it is undefined.

foo.service.ts

```
doObservableThing(): Observable<boolean> {
  return Observable.of(true);
}
```

bar.service.ts

```
doThing(): boolean {
  if (someCondition) { // will be true for the test below
    this.fooService.doObservableThing().subscribe(
      () => { return true; }, 
      () => { return false; });
  } else {
    return false;
  }
}
```

bar.service.spec.ts

```
it('should return true', () => {
  let result = barService.doThing();
  expect(result).toBe(true); // result is undefined
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
doThing(): Observable<boolean> {
  if (someCondition) { // will be true for the test below
        return this.fooService.doObservableThing().map(() => true);
     } else {
        return Observable.of(false);
     }
}
```